# Rails 3 serialized hash values saving but not persisting

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization

I have a model with a serialized text column. When I save and reload the record, the values seem to persist but when I query the record the values are gone.

(Demonstration below truncated for simplicity)

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :pending_changes, Hash
   attr_accessible :pending_changes
   attr_accessor :pending_changes
end

class AddPendingChangesToSubscriptions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :subscriptions, :pending_changes, :text
  end
end

s = Subscription.new

s.pending_changes = {foo: "bar"}

s.save 
# => true

s.reload.pending_changes
# => {foo: "bar"}

Subscription.last.pending_changes
# => nil
```

The same thing happens when saving `{"foo" => "bar"}` as the value.

I've also noticed that when `save` is called, the resulting SQL query is as follows:

```
UPDATE 'subscriptions' SET 'updated_at' = '2017-12-01 23:46:05', 'pending_changes' = '--- {}\n' WHERE 'subscriptions'.'id' = 2
```

As per the answers to similar questions, I've made sure the db column datatype is `text` and I've tried using `serialize :column_name` with and without the appended `Hash`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove attr_accessible :pending_changes and attr_accessor :pending_changes from the model, since you have a column in the database , so no need of using attr_accessible, attr_accessor. Use the model code as below and try.

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :pending_changes, Hash
end
```

Comment: Well that did the trick! Thanks. I've gotten in the habit of setting `attr_accessible` since it's required for mass assignment (in my experience). I can do without that in this case. Are you familiar with WHY `attr_accessible` and the serialized data conflict?